# How to click the button as per the html using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am learning Selenium and trying to click the `GO` button:
https://speedtest.telstra.com/

```
<button class="button background-primary-hover text-primary" aria-label="start your speedtest">
<span style="font-size: unset; overflow-wrap: unset;">GO</span></button>
```

What are all possible Selenium methods to get that button clicked, 
`elem = driver.find_element_by_`....???

I also would like to see what I found, so should `print(elem.text)` then be used?

Answer (score 2):

As per the website `https://speedtest.telstra.com/` the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* to switch to the `<iframe>` and then look out for the element and you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='speed-test' and @src='//telstra-nbn.speedtestcustom.com']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button background-primary-hover text-primary']/span[contains(.,'GO')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"//iframe.speed-test[src*='speedtestcustom']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button.background-primary-hover.text-primary[aria-label='start your speedtest']>span"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I have been researching for this very solution for 2 hours. I wish I could found it, but thanks for brightening me up. I did not know `WebDriverWait` this efficient. I learned a lot from this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, so locating the clickable by XPATH. How would I do it using Class name or CSS selectors?

Comment: @user3013157 Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @New contributor, oh thanks so much, I understand it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `xpath`, there is `xpath` helper tool for chrome. You can install it.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath")

button.click()
```

Comment: There is no option to click by xpath in a frame.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("button background-primary-hover text-primary").click()
```

Since it will select the element and click it.